# Multiple Backgrounds CSS

Tags: html, css, background, position

I'm trying to add multiple backgrounds this is my web page www.softglobal.com.mx, It has two headers, one with the logo and the other fills the right top, but I want a background that is behind this other two, how can I even do that, this is the CSS

```
enter code here

This the code

#content-wrap { 
     background: url (http://i.imgur.com/D4ZVVnY.png);
}


 body {

background:           url(http://i.imgur.com/K7yy7nB.png) no-repeat #fff;
width: 100%;
display: table;
margin: 0;
padding:0;

         }




    #templatemo_header {

height: 180px;
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/46t4Zmo.jpg) repeat-x;
background-position:  0 -2px;
margin: 2px 2px 2px 25px;
padding: -3px 0 0 0;
    background: url (http://i.imgur.com/D4ZVVnY.png);
      }


     #ja-cssmenu {
margin:-49px -32px -20px 20px; /* all lists */
padding:0px;
                   }


   ##############################
```

Answer (score 1):

you can using multiple backgrounds just be careful the order in which you use them, see this link for a good reference on how to added them:

http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/

but the issue here is that the image with the logo has a white background, this will not allow the texture image you have to be seeing, you'll have to change the logo image to a png so is transparent, delete all the white areas, otherwise they will block the texture underneath.

Comment: I didn't know that, I'll give it a try and see what happens

Comment: Hey there, I already tried the png with the same css, only .png but doesn't seem to work. what am I doing wrong? I don't really understand the way I should place them, can you give me a hand? @user2321716

Comment: yeah, you can't use the same css! you'll have to add both background images to the header element, something like this:                          header{                                                                  background: url('image_path.png'),                                            url('second_image.png');                                              }                                                                      pay attention to the trailing come after the first url, if you forget it it won't work. Add a code pen if you want me to see your code.

Comment: Thank you so much, I managed to get it fixed by using same background. but I will try to do it with this method. Thank you so much.